# how to get specific href url with beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the download URL in this **td** tag

```
<a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/18SEP19/GS07F5933RSPEFA519F0433.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Delivery Order Document"><img alt="PDF Document" border="0" height="16" hspace="2" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" width="16"/></a>, <a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/18SEP19/GS07F5933RSPEFA519F0433.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Delivery Order Document">SPEFA519F0433</a>
```

The output above was produced by my code is:

`downloandurl=batch.select("a[href*=https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/]")`

how do I get the **href** URL from the tag

I am trying to retrieve this

> https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/18SEP19/GS07F5933RSPEFA519F0433.PDF

Comment: what was the start url?

Answer (score 0):

Please use proper tags for your questions, and share your code, so we know how much you have done rather than providing the entire answer. Thanks,

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re
''' Don't forget to install/setup package = 'lxml' '''



url = "http://www.github.com"

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')

tags = soup.find_all('a')

''' This will print every available link'''

for tag in tags:                       
    print(tag.get('href'))

''' this will print links with only prefix as given'''
for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://github")}):
    print(link.get('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `href` value from anchor tag.

Use

- tag['hef']

OR

- tag.get('href')

OR

- tag.attrs.get('href')

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/18SEP19/GS07F5933RSPEFA519F0433.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Delivery Order Document"><img alt="PDF Document" border="0" height="16" hspace="2" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" width="16"/></a>, <a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/18SEP19/GS07F5933RSPEFA519F0433.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Delivery Order Document">SPEFA519F0433</a>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('a'):
    print(item['href'])
    print(item.get('href'))
    print(item.attrs.get('href'))
```

---

If you looking after some specific anchor tag then add more condition in find tag like.

```
for item in soup.select('a[target="DIBBSDocuments"]'):
    print(item['href'])
    print(item.get('href'))
    print(item.attrs.get('href'))
```

OR Starts-with href url.

```
for item in soup.select('a[href^="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards"]'):
    print(item['href'])
    print(item.get('href'))
    print(item.attrs.get('href'))
```